# find if char is in string in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I looked all over the NSString class reference but I can't seem to find out if I have a string, what method can I use to check if a particular character is inside of the string.

For example, if my string is

```
NSString * string = "123.32"

if ([string hasString:@"."]) {
//do stuff
```

so I don't really care the index that it is at but whether it has it or not :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `rangeOfString:` — so, for example, `[string rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound`.

Comment: Hmmmmm, this doesn't seem to work for me.  This is my code            
    NSString * decimal = sender.currentTitle;
            if ([self.display.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound){
                NSLog(@"Decimal was detected");
                self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:decimal];
    }
but when I press the decimal button the log message does not appear.

Comment: Alternatively, I tried the following:
    NSString * decimal = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([self.display.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"."]){
        NSLog(@"Decimal was detected");
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:decimal];
    }
and the "decimal is pressed" log message does appear. I might be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Forget that. This actually doesn't work either. hmmmmm, any ideas why this wouldn't work for me?

Comment: @GuillermoAlvarez: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or logging outside of any conditional in the method to make sure that 1) it's actually running and 2) the string is actually what you think it is? Because that code doesn't look like it should fail for any string containing ".".

Comment: Ok scratch that....this works fine. I had something else messed up in my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I ask a related question. How do you know to use the location property with the rangeOfString method?

Comment: @GuillermoAlvarez: Because the documentation for NSString says it returns an NSRange, and that the NSRange will be `{NSNotFound, 0}` if it couldn't find the string. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html